# Background color of tr is not changing using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to change the background olor of a tr while clicking on its child td.I cant add `onclick` to tr since it is dynamically generating from a gridview control of asp.net after rendering.

my mark up is

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td style="width:27%;"><span onclick="SelectAddressRow(this)">Ajish</span></td>
    <td style="width:40%;"><span onclick="SelectAddressRow(this)">22</span></td>
    <td style="width:33%;"><span onclick="SelectAddressRow(this)">Male</span></td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
```

my code is

```
function SelectAddressRow(column) {
  var tableRow=$(column).parent();
  $(tableRow).parent().css({ "background-color": "#B3B3B3" });
}
```

but it is not working,But it affects for a td if the statement is replaced by

```
$(tableRow).css({ "background-color": "#B3B3B3" });
```

Comment: can you create the fiddle for same??

Comment: Works for me, at least if I correct the case mismatch error... http://jsfiddle.net/Xd75H/

Answer (score 1):

What about this approach. Since you are using jQuery, it doesn't make sense to use inline javascript:

```
$('table').on('click', 'span', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').addClass('selected');
});
```

CSS:

```
.selected {
    background: #B3B3B3;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m5D85/

Comment: @Arvin It will add another class.

Comment: Im  writing the functions in a seperate .js page

Answer (score 0):

You are very close. you have defined parameter as `column` and using `Column`

```
function SelectAddressRow(column) {
  var tableRow=$(column).parent();
  $(tableRow).parent().css({ "background-color": "#B3B3B3" });
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/dP57a/)

Alternatively, you can use [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
function SelectAddressRow(column) {
  $(column).closest('tr').css({ "background-color": "#B3B3B3" });
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/dP57a/1/)

Comment: Changing but onle the td I click, not yet the tr

Comment: @Arvin, its changing tr see it using developer tools

Comment: Both are not working when i use it in visual studio 2010 and mozilla firefox

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td style="width:27%;"><span onclick="SelectAddressRow($(this).closest('tr'))">Ajish</span></td>
    <td style="width:40%;"><span onclick="SelectAddressRow($(this).closest('tr'))">22</span></td>
    <td style="width:33%;"><span onclick="SelectAddressRow($(this).closest('tr'))">Male</span></td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
```

and change the function to look like this:

```
function SelectAddressRow(row) {
  var tableRow=row;
  tableRow.css({ "background-color": "#B3B3B3" });
}
```